# Why multiple value for same name appended to formData using JS AJAX sends to PHP only the last one

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send multiple files to my PHP with AJAX by appending each file to the formData with the same name on the append.
When log it to the JS console the formData entry is well done with the multiple entries but when i send it to PHP i get only the last one.
Is the same if instead of files are just strings or whatever.

I know i could append data to the formData to form an array setting the name like `.append('name[]', whateverValue);` but then in the server, when is files, instead of an array of files with their keys: values is multiple arrays one for each key.

This is my JS code:

```
let formData = new FormData()

formData.append('file', files[0])
formData.append('file', files[1])

console.log(formData.getAll('file'))

$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: '../php/_DEBUG.php',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData

}).done(response => console.log(La.parse.maybeJSON(response)))
```

In my PHP code i just echo the json encoded $_FILE array or the $_POST when i test it wihtout being files. So the response is only the last file added (file[1]) in this case and if i echo the COUNT of $_FILE['file'] is 1.

This is what it shows `console.log(formData.getAll('file'))`:
[Result of JS console.log of the formData before send it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFeLb.png)

This is the response of the server when the PHP code is `echo json_encode($_FILE);`:
[Result of PHP response showing only the last file has been sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR12M.png)

And this is the response if i append files to the formData with the '[]' on the name:
[Result of PHP response when multiple files are added using array constructor on the append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6FZf.png)

So i would like, to be able to send the files or whatever without using the '[]', just appending with the same name and get it as an array in the PHP since the formData is well done in the JS and the official documentation recommend do it like that withouth the '[]'.

Comment: Try naming it to: `formData.append('file[]', files[0])`. The `[]` after the name indicates that it can contain multiple values and PHP will store them as an array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thats what i said it results as multiple arrays each one with the name of the keys of the files object and not a single array with the multiple files.

Comment: That's what the file array looks like when you upload multiple files. It's normal and correct. You can read more about it [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)